# react-native using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created app using 'react-navigation' and first navigation working fine.
I want to add a button to the header and I want to redirect it to the UserLogin page.
this is the solution I found based on my research

**Button title = "Profile" onPress = {() => {props.navigation.navigate('UserLogin')}} />**

I know I'm doing something missing or wrong, but I can't find a round.Home user login and all redirects pages are below

**HOMESCREEN**

```
// import { List,ListItem,SectionList,FlatList, Container, Header, Content, Accordion, AcitivityIndicator, View, Text } from "native-base";
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
 Image,
 Platform,
 ScrollView,
 StyleSheet,
 TouchableOpacity,
 Button,
 FlatList
} from 'react-native';

import { Container, Header, Content, Icon, Accordion, Text, View } from "native-base";



function HomeScreen(props) {

   return (
     <Container>
       <Content>
         <Text>
           HOME
       </Text>
       <Button title="Profile" onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('UserLogin')}} />
       </Content>
     </Container>
   );
 }



HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
 title: 'RESTAURANT',
 headerRight: () => (
<Button title="Profile"  onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('UserLogin')}}  />
 ),
 headerLeft: () => (
   <TabBarIcon
     onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
     name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'md-person' : 'md-link'}
     style={{ marginRight: 115 }}
   />
 ),
};


export default HomeScreen;
```

**USERLOGIN(PROFILE) SCREEN**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default function UserLoginScreen() {

    return (
      <ScrollView >

        <Text> UserLoginScreen </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  UserLoginScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'RESTAURANT',
   };
```

**MAINTABNAVIGATOR**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import FoodScreen from '../screens/FoodScreen';
import DrinkScreen from '../screens/DrinkScreen'; 
import OrderScreen from '../screens/OrderScreen';

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: 'screen' },
  default: {},
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
  },
  config
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home'}
    />
  ),
};

HomeStack.path = '';

const FoodStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Food: FoodScreen,
  },
  config
);

FoodStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Food',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'md-restaurant' : 'md-restaurant'} />
  ), 
};

FoodStack.path = '';




const DrinkStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drink: DrinkScreen,
  },
  config
);

DrinkStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Drink',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'md-wine' : 'md-wine'} />
  ),
};

DrinkStack.path = '';


const OrderStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Orders: OrderScreen,
  },
  config
);

OrderStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Order',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-basket' : 'ios-basket'} />
  ),
};

OrderStack.path = '';

// const UserLoginStack = createStackNavigator(
//   {
//     UserLogin: UserLoginScreen,
//   },
//   config
// );

// UserLoginStack.navigationOptions = {
//   tabBarLabel: 'UserLogin',
//   tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
//     <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-basket' : 'ios-basket'} />
//   ),
// };

// UserLoginStack.path = '';

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  FoodStack,
  DrinkStack,
  OrderStack,
});

tabNavigator.path = '';




export default tabNavigator;
```

Comment: Uploading your code to the Expo can help you more

Comment: https://expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/rest-pay-app

Comment: i cant see your code

Comment: You can look with github https://github.com/ibrahimyolbir/res-pay. I dont know how i can publish with expo. @yoel

Comment: https://github.com/ibrahimyolbir/res-pay/blob/master/res_pay_frontend/screens/HomeScreen.js                       
  There are 2 'on press buttons' on the page. One of them is in 'render' (this works smoothly). The other is in 'HomeScreen.navigationOptions'. This 'onpress button' doesn't work, I get (props) error.